# Pivoting the dataframe to convert certain rows in to columns base on one specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dns

I have a dns dataset containing records that looks like below:-

```
Query_Type    Query_name    Response_ttl    ip4_address  NS_Name         MX_Name
  A             google.com      400            1.1.1.1     null                  null
  A             google.com      600            2.2.2.2     null                  null
  NS            google.com      500            3.3.3.3     ns1.google.com        null
  MX             google.com     400            null        null                  gmail.com
  A             facebook.com    400            4.4.4.4     null                  null
  NS            facebook.com    500            5.5.5.5     ns1.facebook.com      null
  .
  .
```

I want the  expected output table to  merge all records based on Query_name and all other columns to be rows like below:-

```
**Query_name  Query_type_A_ip   Query_type_A_ttl Query_type_NS_Name Query_type_NS_ttl ...**
 google.com    1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2   avg(400+600)      ns1.google.com        400
 facebook.com   4.4.4.4          avrg(ttls of A)  ....
```

I know that pandas library has **pivot** function to do such thing. But just dont know how to do it. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) first, remove missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), last flatten `MultiIndex` by `map`:

```
df = (df.melt(['Query_Type','Query_name','Response_ttl'], value_name='ip')
        .dropna(subset=['ip'])
        .pivot_table(index='Query_name', 
                     columns=['Query_Type', 'variable'], 
                     aggfunc={'Response_ttl':'mean','ip': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))})
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,2]))
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}_{x[2]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
     Query_name  Response_ttl_A_ip4_address  ip_A_ip4_address  \
0  facebook.com                       400.0           4.4.4.4   
1    google.com                       500.0  1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2   

   Response_ttl_MX_MX_Address ip_MX_MX_Address  Response_ttl_NS_NS_Address  \
0                         NaN              NaN                       500.0   
1                       400.0        gmail.com                       500.0   

   ip_NS_NS_Address  Response_ttl_NS_ip4_address ip_NS_ip4_address  
0  ns1.facebook.com                        500.0           5.5.5.5  
1    ns1.google.com                        500.0           3.3.3.3
```

Or if address columns values are not important omit them:

```
df1 = (df.melt(['Query_Type','Query_name','Response_ttl'], value_name='ip')
         .dropna(subset=['ip'])
         .pivot_table(index='Query_name', 
                      columns='Query_Type', 
                      aggfunc={'Response_ttl':'mean','ip': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))})
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
     Query_name  Response_ttl_A              ip_A  Response_ttl_MX      ip_MX  \
0  facebook.com           400.0           4.4.4.4              NaN        NaN   
1    google.com           500.0  1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2            400.0  gmail.com   

   Response_ttl_NS                      ip_NS  
0            500.0  5.5.5.5, ns1.facebook.com  
1            500.0    3.3.3.3, ns1.google.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got an error while second code **TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found**  in `aggfunc={'Response_ttl':'mean', 'ip':', '.join})` in this line. Actually to give you a background I am loading dataframe from avro file. So it has schema, due to which response_ttl is an integer value.

Comment: @ChiragSharma - Then change `aggfunc={'Response_ttl':'mean', 'ip':', '.join})` to `aggfunc={'Response_ttl':'mean', 'ip': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))})` for convert values to strings

Comment: Since the aggfunc clubs all other columns in one single coloumn ip_query_type, is there a way to select particular columns to be added in **aggfunc**  and not all

Comment: @Chirag Sharma Do you think filter columns after `df.melt(['Query_Type','Query_name','Response_ttl'], value_name='ip')` like `df.melt(['Query_Type','Query_name','Response_ttl'], value_name='ip')[['Query_Type','Query_name','Response_ttl', 'ip']]`, then because column `variable` not, so it is omited.

Comment: This would add the ip column as `id_vars` . is it possible to give multiple selected columns in `value_vars` in melt function